# Top Bottom pairings based on column values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to generate Sector/Group wise pairs from a DataFrame based on the values in it's Score column.

```
+---------+-------------------+---------+
|  Ticker |      Sector       |   Score |   
+---------+-------------------+---------+
|   ABC   |    Energy         |    3.5  |     
|   XYZ   |    Energy         |    4.5  |     
|   PQR   |    Tech           |    5.5  |     
|   MNP   |    Tech           |    1.5  |     
|   JKL   |    Energy         |   10.5  |     
|   BCA   |    Energy         |    8.5  |     
|   RDB   |    Tech           |    6.5  |
|   JMP   |    Tech           |    2.5  |
+---------+-------------------+---------+
```

From above example in sector Energy JKL/ABC would be one such pairing as JKL is highest and ABC is lowest scorer in that sector.Similarly next pairing within Energy  would be BCA/XYZ as BCA is second highest and XYZ is the second lowest within that sector.

As a next step I would like to retain those pairs within each sector where the pair-difference is greater than a certain threshold.

Thank you for your help.

Output can be

```
+---------+-------------------+---------+
|  Ticker |      Sector       |  Result |   
+---------+-------------------+---------+
|   ABC   |    Energy         |    0    |     
|   XYZ   |    Energy         |    0    |     
|   PQR   |    Tech           |    1    |     
|   MNP   |    Tech           |    0    |     
|   JKL   |    Energy         |    1    |     
|   BCA   |    Energy         |    1    |     
|   RDB   |    Tech           |    1    |
|   JMP   |    Tech           |    0    |
+---------+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I will do

```
df=df.sort_values('Score')
df=df.assign(New=df.groupby('Sector').cumcount()%2)

df=df.assign(New2=(df.groupby('Sector').New.apply(lambda x :x.cumsum().replace(0,len(x)/2))))


df.groupby(['Sector','New2']).Ticker.apply(list)
Out[1464]:
Sector     New2
Energy     1       [XYZ, BCA]
           2       [ABC, JKL]
Utilities  1       [JMP, PQR]
           2       [MNP, RDB]
Name: Ticker, dtype: object
```

Then

```
df['Result']=(df.Score==df.groupby(['Sector','New2']).Score.transform('max')).astype(int)
df.sort_index()
Out[1471]: 
  Ticker     Sector  Score  New  New2  Result
0    ABC     Energy    3.5    0     2       0
1    XYZ     Energy    4.5    1     1       0
2    PQR  Utilities    5.5    0     1       1
3    MNP  Utilities    1.5    0     2       0
4    JKL     Energy   10.5    1     2       1
5    BCA     Energy    8.5    0     1       1
6    RDB  Utilities    6.5    1     2       1
7    JMP  Utilities    2.5    1     1       0
```

Edit : As per op adding the `diff`

```
df['DIFF']=df.groupby(['Sector','New2']).Score.apply(lambda x : x.diff().bfill())
df.sort_index()
Out[1479]: 
  Ticker     Sector  Score  New  New2  Result  DIFF
0    ABC     Energy    3.5    0     2       0   7.0
1    XYZ     Energy    4.5    1     1       0   4.0
2    PQR  Utilities    5.5    0     1       1   3.0
3    MNP  Utilities    1.5    0     2       0   5.0
4    JKL     Energy   10.5    1     2       1   7.0
5    BCA     Energy    8.5    0     1       1   4.0
6    RDB  Utilities    6.5    1     2       1   5.0
7    JMP  Utilities    2.5    1     1       0   3.0
```

Comment: Yes! great almost there, is there a way to add another column with score differential for each pairing? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
(
    df.groupby('Sector')
    .apply(lambda x: [df.Ticker.iloc[x.Score.idxmin()],
                      df.Ticker.iloc[x.Score.idxmax()],
                      x.Score.idxmin(), x.Score.idxmax()])
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .set_axis(['Low Ticker', 'High Ticker', 'Low', 'High'],
              axis=1, inplace=False)
    .assign(Diff = lambda x: x.High-x.Low)
)

Out[653]: 
          Low Ticker High Ticker  Low  High  Diff
Sector                                           
Energy           ABC         JKL    0     4     4
Utilities        MNP         RDB    3     6     3
```

Then you can retain those pairs within each sector where the pair-difference is greater than a certain threshold by filtering the Diff column.

Comment: This is close but only focuses on one pair per sector, I want to have multiple pairs per Sector. For each sector Top TCKR/Bottom TCKR,  Second from top TCKR / Second from Bottom TCKR, Third from Top TCKR/ Third from Bottom TCKR etc